# In MacOS X, how do I prevent a folder with extension .theme being treated as a package?

Tags: macos, finder

So I have a folder name ending in .theme and I can't change it to anything else. (It's part of a Plone installation with XDV.) This makes OS X think it's an iDVD theme, not a folder. To browse its contents, I have to right-click "Show Package Contents". How do I make Finder treat it like a normal folder? (I don't use iDVD.)

Comment: Remove the extension?

Comment: No, as I said in my question, I can't change or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iDVD's `Info.plist` defines the file type and that it's a package. Therefore, you need to get rid of it, or edit the `Info.plist`. Since the latter is likely a major pain, and you don't use it anyway, remove it.

---

Uninstall iDVD (if possible), or delete the iDVD application bundle.

---

Then either rebuild the launch services database by entering the following in Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/\
LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
-kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

**or** restart your machine.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be "easier" to modify the <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key><true/> to <false/> underneath the <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key><array><string>theme</string></array>in iDVDs info.plist?

Comment: @Asmus I don't have iDVD installed and didn't know the `plist` format -- and I cannot assume that someone has the Developer Tools installed. Plus, you'd have to remember to repeat this every time there's an iDVD update (granted, there don't seem to be many of those AFAIK). Since he doesn't use it, he can simply trash it.

Comment: Ah, you´re right on updates, forgot about that. Well the other option to do this (by associating .theme files with another .app that has LSTypeIsPackage:false) is way over the top, so I guess your answer is the "easiest" way to go :-)

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I deleted the iDVD application bundle and restarted, which fixed my problem. It seems the Terminal command wasn't needed (I also didn't seem to have LaunchServices.framework/ or lsregister on my computer.)