# Treat folders with an extension like .service as regular folders instead of bundles in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Is there a way to force Finder to treat a folder named `whatever.service` as a folder and not a service?

To make it very clear it's easy to recreate my issue. I just created a new folder, rename it to `name.service` and I can no longer open the folder. Also, the file info does not let me change the kind or choose a different program to open with.

Comment: Does Right click (Ctrl-click) and "Show Package Contents" not do what you want?

Comment: @Doon, Not when we need to use it in an output path for other software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Directories with file extensions" (bundles) are a common way on OS X to bundle stuff consisting of multiple files into a single package, such as kernel extensions, iWork files (before iWork 09), iMovie projects, applications, etc.

You [usually](https://superuser.com/questions/247055/in-macos-x-how-do-i-prevent-a-folder-with-extension-theme-being-treated-as-a-p/247100#247100) can edit an application's `Info.plist` file to remove the definition of the offending bundle it defined — e.g. `.theme` for iMovie.

As `.service` is defined for system *Services* (see e.g. `/System/Library/Services` — access them from the application menu bar item, then select *Services*), you'd probably break stuff by removing this definition.

If you're feeling lucky:

Open `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` for example using Xcode (after changing the file and directory permissions using `chmod` in Terminal) and remove the offending entry in the *CFBundleDocumentTypes* array.

[image]

You need admin permissions to do this. I recommend having current backups. It's possible something breaks if this association isn't purely cosmetic.

Comment: I wonder what [disabling them through RCDefaultApp does](http://i.imgur.com/C1SFx.png).

Comment: @slhck Run `opensnoop` and see what happens on your disk when you change that setting.

Comment: I tried commenting out the entry in `CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`, but it didn't affect the way `.service`s are treated by Finder.

Comment: @Lri Have you updated the Launch Services database as described in the linked topic? I forgot to mention it again here.

Comment: @DanielBeck Not the first time, but I tried commenting it out again followed by resetting the LS database. Still no effect.

Comment: I should've mentioned this earlier, but both times I tried modifying `CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` it nearly locked me out of OS X. No graphical applications launched after a normal login. Restoring `CoreTypes.bundle` from a Time Machine backup appeared to fix it. (I'm still pretty puzzled why that happened — I didn't change the permissions or owner of the `Info.plist` and shouldn't have invalidated it.)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination db, and thanks for doing the trial and error Lri. I think I'll change the way I name development folders in the future, that sounds safer.

Comment: seems like a bad practice from macOS - curious why only few are affected by this?